# Django with django-nose: two identical settings files with different behavior in running test command

Tags: django, django-testing, django-settings, django-nose

With Django 1.4.5, I'm using django-nose 1.1.0.

I have two settings files with no diff.

```
-> % diff local_settings.py test_settings/sqlite.py
```

I run the tests with:

```
-> % python manage.py test foo --settings=local_settings
```

and I get

```
Ran 91 tests in 5.273s
OK (SKIP=6)
```

Running the same identical settings from the different location

```
-> % python manage.py test foo --settings=test_settings.sqlite
```

The tests bail without all running:

```
Ran 43 tests in 1.230s
FAILED (errors=1)
```

I get a traceback, `DatabaseError: no such table: django_content_type`
The traceback comes through the loading of the urls. Something that gets instantiated there calls `ContentType.objects.get_for_model(self.model)`. How is this difference possible when the settings are identical?

My manage.py file is generic:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from django.core import management

if __name__ == "__main__":
    management.execute_from_command_line()
```

Comment: What happens if you move `local_settings` under `test_settings` package and run tests again with `--settings=test_settings.local_settings`? Also, please, check if there is anything in `test_settings/__init__.py`.

Comment: same, nothing in `__init__.py`

Comment: Ideally it'll be great to see what is in your identical settings files.

Answer (score 1):

Is your database `NAME` set to a relative path for the sqlite DB?

If so, you may simply need to syncdb with your settings file in test_settings.

`DatabaseError: no such table: django_content_type` means one of the django specific tables isn't found, which sounds like an issue with the DB itself, not your app or the settings file itself.

Comment: What happens if you run `python manage.py syncdb --settings=test_settings.sqlite` and then run the test command again?